# How to merge several Lists into one List

Tags: neo4j, cypher

To find a node's neighbors,I use query sentence as below

`MATCH (self:Person {id:"13619240353"})-[r*1..2]-(N) return collect(r)`

Then I get the result like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV5Qg.png)

Here r is a list of relations,thus collect(r) is a list of lists,but I expect to
 return a list of relations including all the relations in the collect(r),and without the duplicates.How to write the query?

Answer (score 0):

Since with the variable length of the pattern, the named result is an list, then you need to [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/#unwind-unwinding-a-list) it and use a [`DISTINCT`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/operators/#query-operators-aggregation) to remove duplicates:

```
MATCH (self:Person {id:"13619240353"})-[rs*1..2]-(N) 
UNWIND rs AS r
RETURN collect(DISTINCT r)
```